# Modify this code to convert mySTR to BSTR

Tags: c

I have been grappling with a problem for some time and after breaking it down to its simplest form I now realise I just need to convert an array to a BSTR and make that BSTR available in VBA. Therefore this is the full sample code I need to fix.

```
STDAPI GetMyCode(BSTR in, BSTR out, int cch, double *int1, double *int2, double *int3)
{
LCMapStringW(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LCMAP_LINGUISTIC_CASING | LCMAP_UPPERCASE, in, SysStringLen(in), out, cch);
char myStr[60];
strcpy_s(myStr, 60, out);
return S_OK;
```

When I convert it into a DLL and call it with the following VBA, the result is "HÉLLO WORLD" - Absolutely perfect.

```
GetMyCode StrPtr("héllo world"), StrPtr(cch), 256, -32.12345, 115.11111, 23.5
debug.print cch
```

Although it works, part of the code isn't compiling correctly, namely *strcpy_s(myStr, 60, out);* because *out* is a BSTR and *myStr* is char. How do I modify the code to get the value of myStr out of the function into VBA.

By way of background my end program will only need 3 doubles as input. The code I have already turns those 3 doubles into a 9-60 character long string so ultimately it will be that character string that I will need to convert to BSTR. If I can get the above to work I am reasonably confident that the rest will be achievable.

Comment: It is very unclear if you are trying to convert BSTR to char* or vice versa.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I need to convert myString, which is char, to BSTR and make that available to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you  need [ConvertStringToBSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/convertstringtobstr?view=msvc-170)

```
// ConvertStringToBSTR.cpp  
#include <comutil.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  
  
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw.lib")  
#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")  
  
int main() {  
   char* lpszText = "Test";  
   printf_s("char * text: %s\n", lpszText);  
  
   BSTR bstrText = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR(lpszText);  
   wprintf_s(L"BSTR text: %s\n", bstrText);  
  
   SysFreeString(bstrText);  
}
```

Comment: Garr Godfrey (sorry couldn't get the @ to stick)  Thanks, but that has come up with a heap of errors from comutil.h starting with identifier "class" is undefined. Please bear in mind that I know next to nothing about C